# How to add custom start options in VS package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I need to add custom start options in VS package as shown in the below image.
Any references would be helpful

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: I think that menu simply enumerates installed browsers

Comment: No. A normal web application will simply show it as "Firefox". It shows "Start in Firefox". Also, I am pretty sure that it is customized template. I need to know how?